# Hi, I would like to insert some HTML elements from a PHP, using jQuery Ajax method, in a DOM

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So, I tried this:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'cod.php',  
    type: 'POST',  
    dataType: 'html',   
    success: function(res){  
    $("#tests").html(res);  
    }
```

In my PHP, I have a `foreach` loop that brings me all data from a MySQL query.

```
<?php   
    foreach ($var as $row){  
    echo "<span class='name'>$row</span>";  
    }  
?>
```

The data provided by PHP are something like this:

```
<span class='click' id='name1'>Name1</span>  
<span class='click' id='name2'>Name2</span>
```

The HTML shows correctly the PHP data, returned by Ajax.
e.g.: `Name1`, `Name2`..

But, the `click` handler at the class: `click` doesn't works.

```
$('.click'),click(function(){    
    alert('testing');  
});
```

Please, how do I solve this?

Thank's a lot! ;)

Comment: Assuming it's not just because you typed `$('.click'),click`

Comment: `$('#tests').on('click', '.click', function () {
    alert('testing');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `,` to `.` and use `on` method ([Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)) in jquery for dynamically loaded elements.

Try this:

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {

    alert('testing');
});
```

Comment: Thank's lot Vasu and stackoverflow.com . I'm reading the documentation now. Realy I wrote wrong "," instead of "."  But, the point is about dinamically generate elements. I do not know enough of jquery's behavior, in this case. So, i realy have to lern some more! Thanks! ;)